# How to undo my parition in OSX?

Tags: mac, partitioning, boot-camp, disk-utility

I bought a new Macbook few days back and this is my first experience with MAC. The seller did a partition on my hard disk before giving it to me. I remember him going to 'Disk Utility' for performing a partition.

I came back home and wanted to install Windows 7. I searched Google and read that I need to install it via Boot Camp Assistant. But Boot camp assistant would not allow me to install anything since I dont have a single partition.

How would I restore my partition using Disk Utility?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to erase the second partition, and resize the first one (which will be the only one then) to take up the full space of the disk.

Easiest way to do this is to click on the top left, on `250.06 GB Hitachi`, then click on the `Partition` tab, then you'll see a basic partition map. The rest is fairly simple using the on-screen help and buttons.